# Finding number of pairs having sum as 0 in two different arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm

If I have two seperate sorted arrays, containing equal number of entries, and I need to find the number of pairs(both numbers should be from seperate arrays) having sum = 0 in linear time, how can I do that?

I can easily do it in O(n^2) but how to do it in linear time?

OR should I merge the two arrays and then proceed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the arrays to be sorted.

Stick the numbers from one of the arrays into a hash table. Then iterate over the other array. For each number `n`, see if `-n` is in the hash table.

(If either array can contain duplicates, you need to take some care around handling them.)

P.S. You *can* exploit the fact that the arrays are sorted. Just iterate over them from the opposite ends once, looking for items that have the same value but the opposite signs. I leave figuring out the details as an exercise (hint: think of the merge step of merge sort).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have one doubt, till now I have been using the actual number as a key to its value for the hash table. Since, I have negative numbers now, how do I use them?

Comment: Create two hash tables one for negative numbers (say `n`) and one for positive numbers (say `p`). Use absolute value of number as key for both.For positive numbers search in `n` and for negative search in `p`.

Comment: But both the arrays contain both positive and negative numbers combined. If I do what you suggested, I may get two numbers whose sum comes out to 0 and they may belong to the same array. But I want that both the numbers should belong to different arrays.

Comment: then create two hash tables for first array and two for second.

Comment: Another O(n logn) solution would be to binary search `-x` in the second array. For every `x` belonging to first array.

Answer (score 0):

If they are already sorted, you can traverse them, one frome left to right, one from right to left:

Take two pointers, and put one at the very left of one array, the other at the very right of the other array. Look at both values you currently point on. If the absolute value of one of these values is greater than the other, advance the greater one. If the absolute values are equal, report both values, and advance both pointers. Stop, as soon as the pointer coming from the left reaches a positive value, or the pointer from the right reaches a negative value. After that, do the same with the pointers starting at the resp. other ends of the arrays.

Comment: Thx Jarod, I added a sentence to make this algo correct.

Comment: if array has duplicate elements then it will not work. Say `a = {3,4,5} and b = {-3,-3,-3}`. After matching first `-3` and `3` you are incrementing both markers. Therefore you wont be able to match other two `-3`.

Comment: That's correct, they should not match. 4 and -3 do not sum up to 0.

Comment: Yes they should not match 4 and -3 but other two -3s should get matched with 3.
Solution shoud be `(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)` (assuming index starts from 0) but your solution will give only `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Ah, I thought you could use each number only once. If you can use it multiple times, you are right. Well, there are enough answers already, I won't update mine.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
std::size_t count_zero_pair(const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2)
{
    assert(is_sorted(v1.begin(), v1.end()));
    assert(is_sorted(v2.begin(), v2.end()));

    std::size_t res = 0;
    auto it1 = v1.begin();
    auto it2 = v2.rbegin();

    while (it1 != v1.end() && it2 != v2.rend()) {
        const int sum = *it1 + *it2;
        if (sum < 0) {
            ++it1;
        } else if (0 < sum) {
            ++it2;
        } else { // sum == 0
            // may be more complicated depending
            // how you want to manage duplicated pairs
            ++it1;
            ++it2;
            ++res;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @chanchong: for which entries ? (and as stated duplicate are not managed)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 for(i=0;j=0;i<n&&j<n;)
        {
            if(arr1[i]+arr2[j]==0)
            {
                count++;
                i++;
                j++;
            }
            else if(arr[i]>arr[j])
            {
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It will fail for `arr1[] = {3,4,5}` and `arr2[] = {-3,-3,-3}`.

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia: it is unclear how OP wants to manage duplicate.

Comment: Question says **"I need to find the number of pairs"**.

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia: There may be several pairs without duplicates.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes there may be, but i am just mentioning that above algorithm does not take care of duplicates. If OP does not want to manage duplicates then he can use this.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the solution proposed by @Matthias with an added pointer to catch duplicates. If there is a string of duplicate values in `arr2`, `searchStart` will always point to the one with the highest index so that we can check the entire string against the next value in `arr1`. All values in `arr1` are explicitly checked, so no extra duplicate handling is required.

```
int pairCount = 0;

for (int base=0, searchStart=arr2Size-1; base<arr1Size; base++) {
    int searchCurrent = searchStart;
    while (arr1[base]+arr2[searchCurrent] > 0) {
        searchCurrent--;
        if (searchCurrent < 0) break;
    }
    searchStart=searchCurrent;
    if (searchStart < 0) break;
    while (arr1[base]+arr2[searchCurrent] == 0) {
        std::cout << "arr1[" << base << "] + arr2[" << searchCurrent << "] = ";
        std::cout << "[" << arr1[base] << "," << arr2[searchCurrent] << "]\n";
        pairCount++;
        searchCurrent--;
    }
}

std::cout << "pairCount = " << pairCount << "\n";
```

Given the arrays:

```
arr1[] = {-5, -3, -3, -2, -1,  0,  2,  4,  4,  5,  8};
arr2[] = {-7, -5, -5, -4, -3, -2,  1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8};
```

we get:

```
arr1[0] + arr2[9] = [-5,5]
arr1[1] + arr2[7] = [-3,3]
arr1[2] + arr2[7] = [-3,3]
arr1[4] + arr2[6] = [-1,1]
arr1[6] + arr2[5] = [2,-2]
arr1[7] + arr2[3] = [4,-4]
arr1[8] + arr2[3] = [4,-4]
arr1[9] + arr2[2] = [5,-5]
arr1[9] + arr2[1] = [5,-5]
pairCount = 9
```

Now we come to the question of time complexity. The construction of `searchStart` is such that for each value in `arr1` can have an extra compare with one value in `arr2` (but no more than 1). Otherwise, for arrays with no duplicates this checks each value in `arr2` exactly once, so this algorithm runs in `O(n)`.

If duplicate values are present, however, it complicates things a bit. Consider the arrays:

```
arr1 = {-3, -3, -3}
arr2 = { 3,  3,  3}
```

Clearly, since all `O(n²)` pairs equal zero, we have to count all `O(n²)` pairs. This means that in the worst case, the algorithm is `O(n²)` and this is the best we can do. It is possibly more constructive to say that the complexity is `O(n + p)` where `p` is the number of matching pairs.

Note that if you only want to **count** the number of matches rather than printing them all, you can do this in linear time as well. Just change when `searchStart` is updated to when the *last* match is found and keep a counter that equals the number of matches found for the current `searchStart`. Then if the next `arr1[base]` matches `arr2[searchStart]`, add the counter to the number of pairs.